# Declaring a untyped dependency in a Vue + TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, okta

I'm trying to use [Okta's Vue library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-vue) in a Vue + TypeScript project. In the past, I've been able to use their React library in a React + TypeScript project by creating an `okta.d.ts` file and adding the following to it:

```
declare module '@okta/okta-react';
```

When I try something similar with Vue, I get an error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* vue/types/vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??
ref--13-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!
./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!
./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue/types/vue
```

I looked at [Vue's TypeScript documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) and found that there might be more involved. So I tried:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $auth: any
  }
}
```

Then I changed my `main.ts` to be the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import './registerServiceWorker';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const vue: Vue = new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

export const Auth = vue.$auth;

Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: ...,
  client_id: ...,
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
});
```

However, I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I made some progressing using [@types/okta__okta-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/okta__okta-vue). However, I'm not able to get the callback to work after logging in. Maybe this is due to some changes since 1.0.1 (when the @types module was created)? Here's my [router.ts](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/spring-boot-vue-example/blob/okta/client/src/router.ts). I created a [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30933) to get it updated.

Comment: I was able to get things working after I created my own `ImplicitCallback` component. See https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/issues/352#issuecomment-443065655 for more information. Auth is working, now I’m struggling with Vue issues: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/spring-boot-vue-example/issues